# Confused over which method to use to install?

Tags: installation

I'm a little confused over which way to install Ubuntu 12.

I've been running it in a virtual machine for a while now and I want to make the switch from Windows.  I'd like to have a dual boot, with a large portion of disk space given over to Ubuntu so I can wean myself off Windows. There seem to be so many ways to install it that I'm getting a bit lost.

A link to the correct page would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing it the traditional way: install from a bootable USB stick. Follow the official Ubuntu community help/instructions at [Installation/FromUSBStickQuick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStickQuick).

The instructions include a very simple and easy to follow step-by-step guide.

In my experience, traditional installations (i.e. via bootable USB stick) are better than WUBI (for reference, official instructions are at [Installation/FromWindows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromWindows)) ones for a number of reasons.